# Does Django 1.7 has a automatic way to convert datetime fields from manual HTML form to model?

Tags: python, django, date, datetime, format

I'm writing a simple app that has a form with field who saves the birth_date with format 'd/m/Y'. Due the date format we use in Brazil I'm having to convert the date with the following code to match the format 'Y-m-d':

```
arr_date = request.POST['birth_date'].split('/')
author.birth_date = datetime.date(int(arr_date[2]), int(arr_date[1]), int(arr_date[0]))
```

The form's field is:

```
<input type="date" name="birth_date" value="{{ author.birth_date|date:'d/m/Y' }}"/>
```

Is there a "fancier" way to make this conversion?

Comment: If you use a Django form, it will convert it automatically when you call is_valid().

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but I'm doing this manually to learn how things work from the base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) from standard python library:

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime(str_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks @catavaran it worked. To make this more automatic, I imported my settings.py file in the views.py file (`from django.conf import settings`) and  passed the `settings.DATE_FORMAT[0]` as second argument to the function.

Answer (score 1):

catavaran answer works but also you can use the DJANGO_INPUT_FORMATS setting https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#date-input-formats , it will benefit you if you want to accept many date formats or if you are using several forms in your app.

If you want to display the date you can benefit of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#date-format

Comment: Actually in my settings.py I have the following tuples:
    DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = (
        '%Y/%m/%d',
    )

    DATE_FORMAT = (
        '%d/%m/%Y',
    ) and the USE_L10N property is set to False, but it seems that even with this it's being ignored.